# Update manager is not working on Efika MX (Ubuntu Maverick)

Tags: ubuntu, updates, maverick

When I try to update using the Update manager, I get the following error message:

```
Failed to download repository information: Check your Internet connection.
W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick/main/binary-armel/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick/restricted/binary-armel/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick/universe/binary-armel/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick/multiverse/binary-armel/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-updates/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-updates/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-updates/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-updates/main/binary-armel/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/binary-armel/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-updates/universe/binary-armel/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-updates/multiverse/binary-armel/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-security/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-security/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-security/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-security/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-security/main/binary-armel/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-security/restricted/binary-armel/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-security/universe/binary-armel/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/maverick-security/multiverse/binary-armel/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I know that Maverick is an old and unsupported release but I cannot upgrade to a new release because Efika MX doesn't support them.
I tried to replace "port.ubuntu.com" with "old-releases.ubuntu.com" (as some websites recommended) but it doesn't work either.

What configuration should I change to get updates working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was at [powerdeveloper.org](http://www.powerdeveloper.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=2700&p=17353#p17353) (as pointed out by the official Genesi support):

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security main restricted universe multiverse
```